# Shell - Validating if a single dot is found on a new line

Tags: shell

I have files which sometimes their content is like below:

```
sometexthere1.33
sometexthere2.33
.
sometexthere3.33
```

I have been able to replace certain text but not that dot.
In my case I would like to duplicate the dot when a dot is found by itself on a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find lines with nothing a single dot, and replace them with two dots, by using the command:

```
sed 's/^\.$/../'
```

as in the following transcript:

```
pax> echo 'sometexthere1.33
...> sometexthere2.33
...> .
...> sometexthere3.33' | sed 's/^\.$/../'

sometexthere1.33
sometexthere2.33
..
sometexthere3.33
```

In `sed`, `'s/X/Y/'` will change the first occurrence of `X` into `Y`. In your case, `X` needs to be `^\.$`:

- the start-line marker `'^'`;
- a literal dot, `'\.'`; and
- the end-line marker, `'$'`.

`Y` is, of course, just two dots, `'..'`.